# Posting to 1 twitter account using the twitter API & OAuth

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

Basically, when a user (any of them) posts on my site, I want it to post to the website's twitter account, first I thought RSS, but then I realised there aren't any that update constantly, so onto the API, the problem I have is that using OAuth the posts will be published to the users account, not the sites. I'm using this tut: 
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

Any help would be appreciated (or even better, easier ideas!) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request your oAuthToken and oAuthSecret from Twitter to access your account directly. They should also give you a consumerKey and consumerSecret. The rest is simple:

```
//Create new client.
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

//Send Tweet
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $message));
```